# Работа с циклом

Tags: php

Не могу понять, почему переменная `$colvo_prav` не увеличивается на 1, а выводит кучу цифр? То есть, нужно, чтобы при каждом `true` в конструкукции `if` переменная `$colvo_prav` увеличивалась на единицу. А если `if` `false`, то, соответственно, нет

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 25; $i++)
        {
        $cookie_t = $_COOKIE["otveti".$i];
        $DB->query = "SELECT correct_answer FROM test3 WHERE id=".$i; 
        $correct_answer = $DB->read('correct_answer');
        if($cookie_t != '')
        {
        $DB->query = "SELECT answer".$cookie_t." as otv FROM test3 WHERE id=".$i; 
        $vash_otv = $DB->read('otv');
        }
            $colvo_prav = 0;
            if($correct_answer == $vash_otv){
                $colvo_prav++;
                $verno = "Правильно!";
            }else 
                $verno = "Неправильно. Правильный ответ:".$correct_answer;

            $DB->query = "SELECT question FROM test3 WHERE id=".$i; 
            $question = $DB->read('question');

            $otveti_na_voprosy = "Вопрос №".$i.": ".$question."\nВаш ответ:".$vash_otv." ".$verno."\n\n";

            echo $colvo_prav;
```

Comment: А вы покажите полный код и то, что в итоге выводит.

Comment: Выводит вот это (через echo) - 1111011100000000001000000. Весь код не покажу - он огромный)) Могу описать - `$correct_answer` берет из базы ответ; `$vash_otv` - берет ответ из куков (цифра). В цикле ответы сравниваются между собой. Вопросов 25. Я так понимаю, что в случае верного ответа в echo идет 1, в противном случае - 0. Потому и куча 1 и 0 в выводе. Хотя откуда взялась 1 между нолями, мне непонятно, т.к. я тестил только 8 вопросов

Comment: Вставил полный код в вопрос. Сам по себе код работает корректно. А вот переменную на 1 увеличивать не хочет

Comment: Ответ прост. вы счетчик постоянно обнуляете. `$colvo_prav = 0` должен находится до начала цикла

Comment: Так он до начала цикла и находится - `$colvo_prav = 0;
            if($correct_answer == $vash_otv){
                $colvo_prav++;` Или имеется ввиду цикл for?

Comment: до начала **ЦИКЛА**, а не условия)) ... до `for (...`

Comment: Если вывести переменную за цикл, то вообще какая-то вот такая абракадабра выходит - `0011122222222222222222222`. А вообще вот в таком виде, как в шапке, выходило все правильно. Только нужно, чтобы эти единички сложились в одну цифру и все

Comment: Ну так и `echo $colvo_prav` напишите уже **после** цикла и всё..... а так оно (echo) сейчас внутри цикла каждую итерацию вызывается... поэтому и адабра кадабра

Comment: Вы же не думаете, что я так не пробовал?)) `echo` за циклом выдает ноль

Comment: В общем, решил. Все было еще проще, а никто не заметил - запись $colvo_prav = 0; была лишней

Comment: Собссн, когда я вам говорил `$colvo_prav = 0 должен находится до начала цикла` неужели вы оставили `$colvo_prav` еще и в цикле?

Comment: нет, удалил вообще)) Короче, понял - это TC ступил и не обновил файл на FTP. Спасибо, кстати, за помощь ;)

Comment: Тогда лично я не понимаю как у вас вообще работает если у вас до цикла объявления нет и из цикла вы это сейчас удалили

Comment: Ну а почему не должен работать? В цсловии объявляется переменная со значением 0 по умолчанию. Далее итерируется на единицу в случае выполнения условия)) Все ок

Comment: Где....покажите мне пожалуйста где у вас условие, в котором объявляется переменная со значением  0? Где-то вне кода, который вы предоставили?

Comment: Да нигде) Я оставил код как в вопросе сейчас, но убрал оттуда строчку `$colvo_prav = 0;` и вынес echo за пределы цикла. И все работает)) Само собой, если добавить строчку `$colvo_prav = 0;` до цикла тоже будет работать. И я так и сделал, так как эта запись более верная. Но фишка в том, что работает и так и так)) Чему я тоже удивился

Comment: Просто у вас отключено отображение ошибок, а там наверняка написано, что `Undefined variable` и возможно в зависимости от версии `php` из-за того, что вы не объявили переменную до цикла в итоге у вас не сработает цикл, выдаст ошибку, не отобразит страницу и вы будете гадать что такое.... ну это на будущее........ в общем я понял что я был прав с самого начала)